# How do I make a config file for command line arguments and pass it?

Tags: c++, config, boost-program-options

Somebody gave me a program that uses boost::program:: options to parse a config file for command line arguments.

I would like to know how to make this file and how to pass it?
the program takes in argc and argv for regular command line arguments, so would I pass the name "command_line_arguments.txt" in quotes to the program?

I understand boost:: program :: options takes in INI configuration files, how would you use those for command line arguments?